# Python type hints - specify key, value type for dict subclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-hinting

Say I have

```
class A(dict): pass
```

Is there any way to specify the type of the key and values of A ? Can it be done in a way that the types are inherited - so `class B(A)` would inherit the type values for, say, key and would be able to override the type of value ?

Ideally this would be done via the type hints introduced in [pep-0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) - but note I am on python 2 so I would need a solution with type comments. If however this is not possible a solution involving metaclasses or any other hack would be acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean by *"type comments"*? Do you actually want to enforce the type, or just document it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: See [PEP 484 *Type Comments*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments)

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah thanks, I wondered if the OP was referring to docstrings or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All type interactions with your class go through methods, so annotate those methods. `A.__setitem__(self, key, value):` is called for setting a key-value pair and can be annotated to indicate the types expected.

Any valid PEP 484 annotation would do here, including type comments if you need Python 2 compatibility.

Those annotations would be inherited to `B` unless B overrides the methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot - would the type information propagate in other methods or do I have to annotate them all ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: you have to annotate all methods when subclassing, yes, because the `dict` type itself has no annotations.

Comment: See my edits - so finally no magical way to specify the key/value types as class variables and have this info propagate to all builtin methods ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: can you please create a new post for new questions? Yes, this is related as your new question springs from the old, but your original question was answered.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: no, there is no way to magically apply this that I know of.

Comment: Oh thanks - my question was not as generic - I knew I could override individual methods, I was expecting there would be a way (given one can do `# type : dict[unicode, int]`) to specify key/value type for local  variables or parameters) - so basically this was a clarification on your answer. Can I post it as a new answer as I find the info in there useful ?

Comment: As long as your answer answers your question, sure!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @MartijnPieters [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36811255/281545) (I am using Pycharm 5.0.4 so behavior below may be due to the standard or to an IDE bug/feature)

```
_key_type_global = unicode

class A(dict):

    _key_type = unicode

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """A._key_type is not recognised, _key_type_global is
        :type key: _key_type_global
        :type value: int
        """
        super(A, self).__setitem__(key, value)

class B(A): pass


a = A()
a['str'] = 'uy' # expected type unicode got str instead
a[u'str'] = 'uy' # no warn (?)
a[u'str'] = 1 # no warn

val = a[u'str'] # Pycharm does not give any type info on value so I have to 
# define __getitem__ too

# type info is inherited
b = B()
b['str'] = 'uy' # expected type unicode got str instead
b[u'str'] = 'uy' # no warn (?)
b[u'str'] = 1 # no warn
```

So one needs to override all methods (key value type info is local to the individual methods). IOW, unlike the case for parameters or attributes etc where one can do:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, dct):
        self.dct = dct # type : dict[unicode, int]
```

this is a NOOP:

`class A(dict): # type dict[unicode, int]`

Moreover there seems to be no way to be able to specify the types as class variables which could be readily overridden in subclasses.