# How can I type hint the return type of .values() in a custom dict subclass?

Tags: python, mypy

When I type check the following class with `mypy` it throws an error

> error: Returning Any from function declared to return "Optional[SomeDictValueType]"

in `get_by_id` as the type of `.values()` isn't defined/restricted properly.

```
class SomeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._some_attribute: SomeRandomType = None

    def get_by_id(self, id: str) -> Optional[SomeDictValueType]:
        for p in self.values():
            if p._id == id:
                return p
        return None
```

I found similar questions online and tried the following things:

1. adding type hints to `__setitem__` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811192/python-type-hints-specify-key-value-type-for-dict-subclass)

   ```
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: SomeDictValueType) -> None:
        super(SomeDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
   ```
2. using `Mapping` in the class header as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427687/how-to-add-type-annotations-to-custom-dict-subclass-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

   ```
    class SomeDict(dict, Mapping[str, SomeDictValueType]): ...
   ```

How can I get rid of this error without using `# type: ignore`? Instances of this class will never hold values of a type other than `SomeDictValueType`.

---

**EDIT:**
Here is a minimalistic example to reproduce the error. Save the following code snippet to a python file and execute `mypy --strict <filename>.py` on it.

```
from typing import Optional

class SomeDict(dict):  # type: ignore
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._some_attribute: Optional[str] = None

    def get_by_id(self, id: str) -> Optional[int]:
        for p in self.values():
            if p._id == id:
                return p
        return None
```

The following error should be thrown:

> test.py:10: error: Returning Any from function declared to return
> "Optional[int]"

Comment: It is very difficult to test possible solutions to this problem without having any idea of what the definitions of `SomeRandomType` and `SomeDictValueType` are (or what they *could* be, at least). It would be helpful if you could edit your question to provide a minimal, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlexWaygood the `SomeRandomType` doesn't affect the question in any way, sorry about that. I just wanted to include an `__init__` in my example for convenience. The `SomeDictValueType` can be anything you want and you would get the very same error. But I am going to provide a minimalistic example of the error in an EDIT section ;)

Comment: Try to think about it from a potential answerer's point of view — we have no idea whether the definition of `SomeRandomType` matters or not if we can't test the code ourselves ;)

Comment: yep, sorry about that ^^' i was too quick with writing the question.

Comment: You've solved your problem now, but note for future questions -- your example still wasn't entirely complete, as we had no idea what values were to be stored in this dictionary such that they could be guaranteed to all have an `_id` attribute. An example use case would have been useful.

Comment: @AlexWaygood Yes sorry, next time I'll try to be more thoughtful ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I just figured it out. I thought you cannot subclass from a typing definition (I tried it once at the beginning but got another error and didn't look close enough).
In my opinion, the following snippet would be a solution for the minimalistic error reproducing example.

```
from typing import Optional, Dict

class SomeDict(Dict[str, int]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._some_attribute: Optional[str] = None

    def get_by_id(self, id: str) -> Optional[int]:
        for p in self.values():
            if p == 5:
                return p
        return None
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution, I was just writing it out myself. The issue is that if you inherit from an unparameterised `dict`, MyPy interprets that as `dict[Any, Any]`, so a method that returns one of the dictionary's values must, therefore, return `Any`. Inheriting from a parameterised `dict` solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

mypy is correct. Since you iterate over `values()`, it can not tell what is the type of the dict value, it consider it as `Any`.

Comment: yes but in my case, the class will never be used with another type than `SomeDictValueType`. That is why I want to enforce the type.

Comment: @c0mr4t - so dont extend dict. use `Dict[str,SomeDictValueType]` and make `get_by_id` a util function